# Percentage progress on Automator application(.app) on Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, git-bash, automator

I have used **Automator Application** to create application(**.app** which runs by double clicking). It runs commands which executes command one by one. Every command takes 2-3 minutes. What I want to achieve is show percentage progress after completion of every command.

[image]

In above image percentage is always zero. I want to explicitly set progress after completion of every command. I also know this is possible using **AppleScript** but I want to implement in bash script.

Comment: If it just one "Run Shell Script" action and that shell script contains multiple commands I don't think you can do it. The % complete is the % of actions complete. If you can split your shell script into multiple scripts across several "Run Shell Script" actions then the % complete will update as they finish.

Comment: @tzs I just want to show progress. Which I think is possible to throw using Automator I found sample of automator script on apple documentation but that doesn't show progress either. And of course if we have 10 command and 4 of them are completed we should be able to show 40% completed.

Answer (score -2):

I did this once for a script of mine:

```
progress() {
  set -- "$@" "$((100*$1/$2))" "$(($1 == 0 ? -1 : SECONDS*($2-$1)/$1))"
  printf "%d of %d (%d%%) eta %s sec" "$@"
}
```

You pass it 2 parameters:

1. the current number of the thing you're processing,
2. the total number of things you're processing

Your script will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
progress() {
  set -- "$@" "$((100*$1/$2))" "$(($1 == 0 ? -1 : SECONDS*($2-$1)/$1))"
  printf "%d of %d (%d%%) eta %s sec" "$@"
}

n=10   # you need to hardcode this, the total number of commands to run
i=0

command_01; progress $((++i)) $n
command_02; progress $((++i)) $n
command_03; progress $((++i)) $n
command_04; progress $((++i)) $n
command_05; progress $((++i)) $n
command_06; progress $((++i)) $n
command_07; progress $((++i)) $n
command_08; progress $((++i)) $n
command_09; progress $((++i)) $n
command_10; progress $((++i)) $n

printf "\nThat took %d sec\n" $SECONDS
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is working fine when I run bash script from Terminal. But I have created application(.app) from Automator which runs when you double click on it. So for knowing progress of it I can only show percentage of it on menu bar as attached in Image above.